# PLSQL trigger to raise application error not working

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger which raise error if the total number of row exceeds 10, The plsql code was successfully compiled but it's not generating any error. 
This is the plsql code:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_count_check
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON customer2
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  count_customer NUMBER;
  6  max_customer NUMBER := 10;
  7  BEGIN
  8  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_customer FROM customer2 WHERE cusid = :new.cusid;
  9  IF count_customer >= max_customer THEN
 10  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Customer Table capacity exceeded');
 11  END IF;
 12  END;
 13  /
```

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b4363a9776469a46d55635411a1d24cf Can you provide a fiddle that shows how it doesn't work?

Comment: hey @sticky bit is there any restriction that we have to create this type of trigger in an empty table?

Comment: Seems to be fine for me too. Try to replace `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` by a simple `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` to see if your `SELECT` is working fine?

Comment: @Ajax: No. But look at hotfix's answer, that seems very plausible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would say your trigger does't work as you expect, because your select statement inside return always one row.

you filter on a primary key!

that should work

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER customer_count_check
  2  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON customer2
  3  FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5  count_customer NUMBER;
  6  max_customer NUMBER := 10;
  7  BEGIN
  8  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO count_customer FROM customer2; --WHERE cusid = :new.cusid;
  9  IF count_customer >= max_customer THEN
 10  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20000,'Customer Table capacity exceeded');
 11  END IF;
 12  END;
 13  /
```